# PHP Mailer sending newsletter

Tags: php, email

Wondering if you could guys help me a little bit as I am messing around with PHP mailer, I have this code modified but from here http://www.askapache.com/php/phpfreaks-eric-rosebrocks-phpmailer-tutorial.html

Sending single emails is working fine through PHP mailer(with a different script), but trying to send to multiple emails now with the script below from a database is currently not working.. can you spot whats wrong with it? although I am wondering if it is actually doing anything with the emails from the database.. I am a bit confused.

The script does succeed and print the names, but does not send any emails out! At least none get received..(not in spam either) any help? Sorry if this is very obvious!

```
 <?php
 // Grab our config settings
 require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mail/config.php');

 // Grab the FreakMailer class
 require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mail/lib/MailClass.inc');

 //set execution time limit to 5 minutes 

 $safeMode = ( @ini_get("safe_mode") == 'On' || @ini_get("safe_mode") === 1 ) ? TRUE : FALSE;
 if ( $safeMode === FALSE ) {
  set_time_limit(300); // Sets maximum execution time to 5 minutes (300 seconds)
   // ini_set("max_execution_time", "300"); // this does the same as "set_time_limit(300)"
 }

 echo "max_execution_time " . ini_get('max_execution_time') . "<br>";


       //db connection
  $con = mysql_connect("xx","xx","xx");
 if (!$con)
   {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

 mysql_select_db("xx", $con);

 // Setup body
 $textBody = "Dear {MEMBER_NAME},\n\nTEST";
 $htmlBody = "Dear {MEMBER_NAME},<br /><br />TEST";

 // instantiate the class
 $mailer = new FreakMailer();

 // Get the user's Email
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT displayname,email FROM engine4_users2")or die(mysql_error());


 //lets reset the time limit of the server everytime an email is sent to bypass maximum
  while (1==1) {
   set_time_limit(30); // sets (or resets) maximum  execution time to 30 seconds)
   // .... put code to process in here


    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($sql))
    {
    // Send the emails in this loop.
    $member_name = $row->displayname;

    if($row->MailType == 'html')
    {
    $mailer->Body = str_replace('{MEMBER_NAME}', $member_name, $htmlBody);
    $mailer->IsHTML(true);
    $mailer->AltBody = str_replace('{MEMBER_NAME}', $member_name, $textBody);
    }
    else
    {   
    $mailer->Body = str_replace('{MEMBER_NAME}', $member_name, $textBody);
    $mailer->isHTML(false);
    }
    $mailer->Send();
    $mailer->ClearAddresses();
    $mailer->ClearAttachments();
    $mailer->IsHTML(false);
    echo "Mail sent to: " . $member_name . "<br />";
    }




   usleep(1000000); // sleep for 1 million micro seconds - will not work with Windows servers / PHP4
   // sleep(1); // sleep for 1 seconds (use with Windows servers / PHP4
        if (1!=1) {
     break;
   }
 }



 ?>
```

Comment: What is the purpose to your last `if` command? `if(1 != 1)`? Have you redefined the number elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never set the user's address to the mailer.

```
$mailer->AddAddress($row->email);
```

before `send()` is called. Because you're sending the mail within the loop, every user would get a single mail and no other addresses would be seen.

(the docu's example you linked isn't complete as the comments below disclose)

You could alternatively only put an

```
$mail->AddBCC($row->email);
```

in the loop and the rest of mailer's code after the loop to send one mail to all, but you'd need one (dummy) address as recipient besides the bcc-adresses to get the mail sent.

```
if($row->MailType == 'html')
```

You didn't select MailType in query. Do you have error reporting enabled?

Comment: Thanks, got it working :) I realized like you said, its in a loop so just add the address! No messing about

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you're not using phpmailer? Download the .php files for phpmailer and use this code, works like a charm:

```
<?php
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT displayname,email FROM engine4_users2")or die(mysql_error());

//
//

require_once('../../mailer/class.phpgmailer.php');
require_once ('../../mailer/class.smtp.php');
require_once('../../mailer/phpmailer.lang-en.php');

$debug = new SMTP();
$debug->do_debug = 2;

while ($record = mysql_fetch_array ($sql)) {
$mail = new PHPGMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host = "mail.zzxxyyhost.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->Port = 26; //designated port, could be different, check your host
$mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE; //smtp authentication may be false, check your host
$mail->Username = "username"; //username
$mail->Password = "password"; //password

$mail->From = "from@someone.com"; 
$mail->FromName = "fromsomeone";

$mail->AddBCC($record['email'], $record["displayname"]); //use bcc for hidden emails    
$mail->Subject = "$record["displayname"]";
$mail->Body = "Your body";


            if(!$mail->Send())
            {
               echo 'Message was not sent.';
               echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            }
    // Clear all addresses and attachments for next loop
    $mail->ClearAddresses();
    $mail->ClearAttachments();
}

?>
```

Comment: I am confused, I thought I was using PHPmailer? doesnt your code require me to use SMTP?

Comment: FYI, I use the script above to send out a single email to multiple addresses and it works.

Comment: Yeah, it does require you to use smtp. I noticed you're using the extended version of the mailer. If you include the files I reference into the mailer directory, it will work.

Comment: If your code already works for 1 email address, change your code to use AddBCC and clearAddresses() at the end of each loop

Comment: I have slightly updated my post, different code using the phpmailer class works for sending emails to a single email, although the script I posted there is something wrong with it.. do you see why?

Comment: yea, like 32bitfloat mentioned, you're never initializing the recipient. Add this line of code:  $mailer->AddBCC($record['email'], $record["displayname"]);

Comment: Great! Did you do something different than add the line of code I gave you?